# How to trim expression with wildcard in script?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that parses a URL.
If the query contains the user and the password, it will retrieve this.

I would therefore like to keep the PHP query if necessary.

```
      Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
    
    $url = "http://toto.site:8080/user/password12349876toolong/2716?checkedby:toto.net"
    
    
    $uri = [System.Uri]$url
    $query = $uri.Query
    $IPTVhost = $uri.Host
    $IPTVport = $uri.Port
    $Segments = $uri.Segments.TrimEnd('/')
    $proto = $uri.Scheme
    
    $ParsedQueryString = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($uri.Query)
    
    if(!$query) {
    
    if ($Segments[1].TrimEnd('/') -eq "live"){
    
    
    $username = $Segments[2].TrimEnd('/')
    
    $password = $Segments[3].TrimEnd('/')
    }
    else
    {
    
    $username = $Segments[1].TrimEnd('/')
    $password = $Segments[2].TrimEnd('/')
    }
    }
    
    
    else {
    $username = $ParsedQueryString['username']
    $password = $ParsedQueryString['password']
    }
    cls
    if (!($url -like '\?checkedby\:'))
    {
    echo "this is a chekedby url"
    $filter = $url.TrimEnd("\?checkedby\:toto.net")
    echo "filter : $filter"
    }
    echo "url: $url"
    echo "query: $query"
    echo "host: $IPTVhost"
    echo "port: $IPTVport"
    echo "segment: $Segments"
    echo "proto: $proto"
    echo "username: $username"
    echo "password: $password"
```

I would like to filter a string of characters when I enter a URL in my script (which is often found in the query but not always).
I know it always starts with `"? Checkedby:"` or `"& checkedby:"` and is always at the end of the url.

Problematic: the chain is variable, it can be:

```
http://toto.com:8080/get.php?username=toto&password=toto&checkedby:titi.com
```

or

```
http://toto.com/1234/4321/5678?checkedby:anyone.xyz
```

or

```
http://toto.com/1234/4321/5678?master.m3u8&checkedby:anyelse.to
```

or this crap :

```
http://toto.com:8080/get.php?username=toto&password=toto&type=output.ext?checkedby:titi.com
```

I have tried several methods with TrimEnd but nothing helps.
The only thing that works is an exact expression like:

```
$filter = $url.TrimEnd("\?checkedby\:toto.net")
```

but that doesn't work (and that's normal) with a url that ends in:

```
&checkedby:another.com.
```

So, question :

How to remove everything that starts with:

```
&checkedby:
```

or

```
?checkedby:
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not good with regex but if you want to remove everything after those 2 keywords including them, I believe this should work: `-replace '(\?|&)checkedby:.+'`

Comment: Error !
$filter = $url -replace (\?checkedby:|&checkedby:).+
missing expression
Thank you

Comment: You're missing quotes on the regex expression, copy paste it as literal from my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)
's helpful comment:

Use a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based operation via the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator):

```
'http://toto.com:8080/get.php?username=toto&password=toto&checkedby:titi.com',
'http://toto.com/1234/4321/5678?checkedby:anyone.xyz',
'http://toto.com/1234/4321/5678?master.m3u8&checkedby:anyelse.to',
'http://toto.com:8080/get.php?username=toto&password=toto&type=output.ext?checkedby:titi.com' |
  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '[?&]checkedby:.+' }
```

For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/7nbaiB/1).